# Optimize buffer size in WinSCP

Tags: winscp

Actually, When ever I opened my WinSCP, it is showing

> Host is not communicating for more than 15 seconds and turn off optimize connection buffer size

Please help some this please give some ideas ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP documentation for error message [Host is not communicating for more than 15 seconds](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_host_is_not_communicating) says (among other):

> If the problem repeats, try turning off [Optimize connection buffer size](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_connection).

*(actually there's "Help" button on the error message box, which gets you to that page)*